# How do I view printers of other Windows user profiles?

Tags: windows-7, network-printer

As an admin, remote desktopped to a clients computer, how would I find out what their saved profile network printers are? Is this a registry entry I have to look for? Or is it saved in a specific profile file?

Comment: What have you already tried? What were the results and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I've tried finding the location on google and microsofts reference sites, nothing really shows up for "windows network printer user profile location" they usually pull up with "printer profiles" and not "user profile" printer location, and the microsoft technet site says its in registry but doesn't give the location.

Comment: Are you running Remote Desktop as an administrator, or as the user with networked printers?

Comment: Running it as admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to what I found, the network printers should be listed in the following registry key.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connections
```

I verified this to be true on my Windows 7 Pro machine.

[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3ba6e6a3-ccd6-43b8-8d83-3298cfe5c36d/removing-printers-from-regedit-on-windows-7?forum=w7itprogeneral)
[source](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/check-registry-key-printer-computer-57663.html)